# Why Initializing mediaPlayer outside onCreate() makes app crash?

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, android-memory, java-memory-model

I have a question about where the variables of type MediaPlayer (or any other) should be initialized. Following are 2 codes to make a simple mediaplayer app (with only play pause buttons) illustrating my problem:

Below code makes the app crash:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer= MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.minigun);

    public void play(View view){
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }

    public void pause(View view){
        mediaPlayer.pause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }
}
```

While this one works fine:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer; //in the first code we initialized here

    public void play(View view){
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }

    public void pause(View view){
        mediaPlayer.pause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.minigun); 

    }
}
```

**1**. Why is the above happening?

**2**. When code is run, where in memory is the MediaPlayer object in the first code being stored?

I am
 - using android studio
 - getting no compilation errors
 - testing on emulator

(I'm a newbie, apologies if the questions are too primitive)

Comment: you are using `this` keyword which is activity context which initialize in `onCreate()` method

Comment: you are passing current activity i. e. `this` to `MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.minigun);` while activity has not been initialized yet. After `onCreate` is called an activity is fully initialized. Read [Activity Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html)